# Три кнопки в строке, с одинаковой шириной

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Три кнопки расположить так, чтобы они занимали всю ширину экрана (получается, каждая по 33%). Вот кнопки находятся на одной строке, но занимают не всё пространство:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
```

---

Как один из вариантов: поставить ширину кнопок match_parent, задать вес=1 :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вам надо убрать вес из родителя а детям выдать ширину в `0dp`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб здравствуйте! Соответствует ли теперь вопрос стандартам SO?

Comment: Добрый вечер! По мне так вполне)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выставьте у кнопок `android:layout_width="0dp"`. Так они займут ровно по трети своего парента.